# Using 'at the time of ' instead of the word 'when '

Tags: grammar, sentence, when

> I will go when you come.

Can I use 'at the time of' instead of the word 'when', as follows?

> I will go at the time of your coming.

After the change, Is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: Hello, Muhammad. (1) Yes and (2) No, but you will be considered as either a second-language speaker or an eccentric.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — Let it be.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is: *I will leave at the time you arrive* or *I will depart at the time of your arrival* or *I will leave upon your arrival*. // "Coming"  the way you used it would have worked fine if "coming" didn't have another meaning having to do with religion.  // Have you ever taken a look at our sister site, ELL?

Comment: As your own examples show, you can’t swap when for “at the time of” without other changes.

Comment: Yes; it's a fair enough question to one who's not immersed in English. I'd hate to have to try to sound sensible all the time in France. And English is so quirky. Why, when 'I will go when you come' is fine and 'I will leave at the exact time that you come to give me the tickets' is acceptable if a little stodgy, does 'I will go at the time of your coming' sound ridiculous? It's totally grammatical, and hardly unclear.